# Autocomplete Kendo always return undefined MVC

Tags: model-view-controller, kendo-ui

Now i am using Kendo for Autocomplete text. Database is Northwind. But it always return undefined. I don't know to have any wrong thing?

**View**

```
@(Html.Kendo().AutoComplete()
             .Name("cbRegion")
             .Filter("contains")
             .DataTextField("RegionDescription")) 
             .DataSource(s => { s.Read(r => r.Action("GetSupplier", "AutoComplete")).ServerFiltering(true); })
```

**Controler**

```
public JsonResult GetSupplier() {
    var md = db.Regions.ToList();

    List<RegionInfo> ls = new List<RegionInfo>();

    foreach (var item in md) {
        ls.Add(new RegionInfo{ RegionDescription = item.RegionDescription , RegionID = item.RegionID});
    }

    JavaScriptSerializer ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();

    var json = ser.Serialize(ls);

    return Json(JArray.Parse(json), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

[Image error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aQPw4.png)

Please give me advise. Thanks

Comment: try adding `.DataValueField("RegionID")` as well

Comment: Hi Mantas Čekanauskas. In Kendo UI, don't have DataValueField() method

Comment: Yeah, you are right. Well, now one thing that comes to my mind is `valuePrimitive` property http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/autocomplete#configuration-valuePrimitive . However I have never done this in mvc, but I guest I should be like that `.ValuePrimitive(true)`

Comment: Thanks. I have wrote it in javascript. Then it returns right value. But with the way is @Html.Kendo().AutoComplete() ---> always undefined